# jQuery datepicker exclude dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to do varies type of exclude dates from [jQuery datepicker ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Those are below.

- Single Date      : one or more specific dates.
- Recurrent day    : The days should always disabled from calender e.g; Sunday.
- Recurrent date   : Particular date should be always disabled.
- Period           : Disable dates between the two date ranges.
- Recurrent period : Disable dates between the two date ranges recurrently.

My JSON DATA

> {
>       "single": [
>           "2/4/2012",
>           "3/2/2012"
>       ],
>       "recurrent_day": [
>           0
>       ],
>       "recurrent_date": [
>           28
>       ],
>       "period": [
>           {
>               "from": "2/21/2012",
>               "to": "2/22/2012"
>           }
>       ],
>       "recurrent_period": [
>           {
>               "from": "2/28/2012",
>               "to": "2/29/2012",
>               "period": "monthly"
>           }
>       ] }

How can i do this, Some one help me.

Thanks.

Comment: if jquery provides a clean way to do this, then it is okay, otherwise i would recommend any other datepicker or even custom built.

Comment: what are the potential "period"? You have used "monthly" but that is really just a serious of dates which should be given to "recurrent_date". Do you want yearly? Is there another reason to have "monthly"?

Comment: @Sinetheta: Yes your correct.There is another option yearly.

Comment: I added a "yearly" case to demonstrate that as a well. Let me know how it works ;)

Comment: @Sinetheta:You amused me already, can you clarify my comment please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sneaky use of the `beforeShowDay` callback. Sorry for the delay, I had a bug in the recurrent_period that took me a while to spot. I added a "yearly" case to the test suite. Let me know if there's anything I have over-looked here. Fun question! [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBkhC/29/)

```
var invalid = { "single": [ "2/4/2012", "3/2/2012" ], "recurrent_day": [ 0 ], "recurrent_date": [ 28 ], "period": [ { "from": "2/21/2012", "to": "2/22/2012" } ], "recurrent_period": [ { "from": "2/28/2012", "to": "2/29/2012", "period": "monthly" },{ "from": "2/7/2012", "to": "2/9/2012", "period": "yearly" } ] };
function single(date){
    var USdate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    return ($.inArray(USdate,invalid.single) > -1);
}
function recurrent_day(date){
    return ($.inArray(date.getDay(),invalid.recurrent_day) > -1);
}
function recurrent_date(date){
    return ($.inArray(date.getDate(),invalid.recurrent_date) > -1);
}
function period(date){
    var i, num, period, start, startArray, end, endArray;
    num = invalid.period.length;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        period = invalid.period[i];
        startArray = period.from.split('/');
        start = new Date(startArray[2], (startArray[0] - 1), startArray[1]);
        endArray = period.to.split('/');
        end = new Date(endArray[2], (endArray[0] - 1), endArray[1]);        
        if(date>=start && date<=end){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function recurrent_period(date){
    var i, num, period, recurrence, startArray, endArray, startDay, endDay, start, end;
    num = invalid.recurrent_period.length;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        period = invalid.recurrent_period[i];
        recurrence = period.period;
        startArray = period.from.split('/');
        endArray = period.to.split('/');

        if( recurrence === 'monthly' ){  
            startDay = parseInt( startArray[1], 10);
            endDay = parseInt( endArray[1], 10);
            if( date.getDate() >= startDay && date.getDate() <= endDay ){
                return true;             
            }               
        }else if( recurrence === 'yearly' ){
            start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), (startArray[0] - 1), startArray[1]);
            end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), (endArray[0] - 1), endArray[1]);  
            console.log({start:start.toDateString() ,end:end.toDateString(),day:date.toDateString()})   
            if(date>=start && date<=end){
                return true;
            }  
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        if(single(date)){
            return [false];
        }else if(recurrent_day(date)){
            return [false];
        }else if(recurrent_date(date)){
            return [false];
        }else if(period(date)){
            return [false];
        }else if(recurrent_period(date)){
            return [false];
        }
        return [true];
    }
});
```

Comment: looks like you solved my problem, can you clarify how to do this on fly.i mean while i select the option from select box, ajax call will return the json.here i need to reconfigure the calender.

Comment: When does the ajax happen? If you were using ajax to update a global variable like this `invalid` then you could update it whenever you felt like it. The code above will run every time the datepicker shows up, hence the use of `beforeShowDay`. Each time they try to pick a date it will check the current state of the `invalid` array. Keep in mind this isn't very defensively coded, I would need to know where the data is coming from, and what might/might-not be there (eg: are all ranges always present, just sometimes empty?).

Comment: yes i understand, how single and other functions will get the value of invalid variable. it stored in ajax success. or either can i use functions inside success function.yes some times ranges will be or all will be empty.Thanks for keep helping.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand when the ajax is happening. If the "availability" information isn't changing during the life of the page, then I would load it in early, and not draw the input field until it is available (ie: hide the input field on doc ready, then reveal it again in the success handler of your ajax). Can you describe the life-cycle of your page? When does the "availability" information come, from where, and what changes it?